# What are the auth_*, authn_*, and authz_* modules in Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server

Do I need these modules? What are they for? I'm running WordPress on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html